# cast function results arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 0

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am trying to find the mean for each variable uniquely but I don't know why it's giving error after applying cast function.

```
 library(reshape)
> odata <- read.csv("dummy2.csv")
> msdata <- melt(odata, id=c("A","F"))
> subjmeans <- cast(msdata, A~ variable, mean)
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
>       arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 0

Here is the data I have used.

```
            Timestamp    A              B    C   D    E     F    G           H            I         J 
            2586    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 9   250 1151 458    p1  color   261.8472837 13.27605282 50.20731621
            2836    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 10  150 1371 316    p1  color   41.01219331 2.088502575 25.59470566
            2986    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 11  283 1342 287    p1  color   580.2206477 28.92031693 84.62469724
            3269    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 12  433 762  303    p1  color   138.1303732 7.026104125 36.45742907
            3702    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 13  183 624  297    p1  color   88.20430828 4.489909458 30.87780081
            3885    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 14  333 712  303    p1  color   42.20189569 2.149072905 25.72796039
            4218    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 15  300 753  293    p1  color   51.7880295  2.637077062 26.80156954
            6517    01_Antwerpen_S1.jpg 22  333 601  674    p1  color   466.0525721 23.40488212 72.49074066
            9066    02_Berlin_S1.jpg    27  149 1067 681    p1  color   90.42676595 4.602920212 31.12642447
            9215    02_Berlin_S1.jpg    28  266 1116 757    p1  color   101.8430165 5.18328435  32.40322557
            9481    02_Berlin_S1.jpg    29  217 1020 723    p1  color   314.3962468 15.90906187 55.99993612
            9698    02_Berlin_S1.jpg    30  183 711  781    p1  color   272.045952  13.78825606 51.33416332
            9881    02_Berlin_S1.jpg    31  183 439  776    p1  color   249.9939999 12.68008164 48.8961796
            10064   02_Berlin_S1.jpg    32  167 328  552    p1  color   193.8375609 9.847751174 42.66505258
            10231   02_Berlin_S1.jpg    33  400 310  359    p1  color   68.00735254 3.462531847 28.61757006
            10631   02_Berlin_S1.jpg    34  666 246  336    p1  color   93.40770846 4.754485399 31.45986788
            11297   02_Berlin_S1.jpg    35  333 172  279    p1  color   1105.224412 52.32154317 136.107395
            13679   03_Bordeaux_S1.jpg  40  316 1152 790    p1  color   280.8629559 14.23062355 52.30737182
            13995   03_Bordeaux_S1.jpg  41  583 1424 860    p1  color   134.1827113 6.825784964 36.01672692
            14578   03_Bordeaux_S1.jpg  42  283 1486 979    p1  color   133.9589489 6.814429158 35.99174415
            14861   03_Bordeaux_S1.jpg  43  233 1419 863    p1  color   282.1772493 14.29652823 52.4523621
            15094   03_Bordeaux_S1.jpg  44  266 1149 781    p1  color   998.5128943 47.86171758 126.2957787
            17559   04_Köln_S1.jpg      49  200 151  813    p1  color   590.041524  29.38880547 85.65537204
            17759   04_Köln_S1.jpg      50  183 741  806    p1  color   294.9779653 14.93791111 53.86340444
            17943   04_Köln_S1.jpg      51  216 1035 782    p1  color   81.0246876  4.124771083 30.07449638
            18159   04_Köln_S1.jpg      52  117 1068 708    p1  color   85.80209788 4.367748556 30.60904682
```

Result is same and error is same with IRIS Data too.

```
library(reshape)
 ss <- iris
 msdata <- melt(ss, id=c("Sepal.Length","Species"))
 subjmeans <- cast(msdata, Species~ variable, mean)
```

Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 0

Comment: because I just copied it from the table of excel file

Comment: @Abdou subjmeans <- cast(msdata, A~ variable, mean)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error you are getting with the data you've pasted here.

Comment: How about this with iris data ? I have updated in the quesiton

Comment: I am still not able to reproduce your error. Perhaps, you may want to share your `sessionInfo()`. Update `R` and your packages if they're not the latest versions.

Comment: Woww. Updating the R solves the problem. Weird it is :-(